# same static variable in same memory block

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, static-members

I have a static Arraylist and calling a adapter with these values. Does java recreate this variables in each scope ?

Example

In FirstActivity.java

```
   static  List<Cars> cars;
   new ContentAdapter(this,cars);
```

In ContentAdapter.java

```
  static List<Cars> cars;

  public ContentAdapter(FragmentActivity c,List<cars> ca) {
    mContext = c;
    cars = ca;
  }
```

Does java re-create cars Arraylist ? And how can i avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you've provided, you have an object reference `ca` which gets assigned to your `cars` variable.  That's not recreating the object, it's just making the object accessible via a new variable.  So I don't think you need to worry about the object being recreated.

Comment: Tried to change cars arraylist in ContentAdapter , but it didn't effect FirstActivity ? That's why i think they are not referenced. Am i wrong ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the system doesn't go around changing your objects.  My best guess is that if your `ContentAdaptor` makes a change to your `List<cars>` object, then its changing the same object that was passed into it from `new ContentAdapter(this,cars)`.  So perhaps you've made a mistake in checking whether the original object has changed or not.